# Postfix setup with different domain name, reverse lookup and SPF

Tags: postfix, spf, reverse-dns, dkim, dmarc

I would like to set up Postfix properly to serve multiple virtual domains while complying to all standards and being able to enable security measures like SPF.

- The server has the hostname `server.domain.tld`.
- Postfix has `mydomain` set to `domain.tld`.
- Postfix has `myhostname` set to `server.domain.tld`.
- Postfix has not set `myorigin` to anything.
- The server is hosting a few dozen virtual domains.
- All users have set up `mail.tld` as incoming and outgoing mail server.
- I would like Postfix to act to the outer world as `mail.tld`.

My first thought was to just set `mydomain` and `myhostname` to `mail.tld`. But it seems, that it is advised, that the reverse lookup of `mail.tld` should resolve to the host's IP address (https://serverfault.com/a/366391/162258 for example). While I could do that, I am concerned though, that setting up the reverse lookup to `mail.tld` might lead to problems, when it will be necessary to reverse lookup the host itself.

How can I achieve that Postfix acts as `mail.tld` and that I will be able to specify `mail.tld` as MX record and use SPF, DKIM and DMARC with it, while retaining the DNS integrity of the host `server.domain.tld`?

Comment: Never name a host with only a naked domain name. This will break email in a variety of ways, at least one of which could cause the mail server to become a spam relay.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I will probably go for something like `smtp.mail.tld`. Thanks for pointing out. Meanwhile I also found a good wiki page about dealing with this hosting question (https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Mailserver_Hostnamen/en). I will give those recommendations a try.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar working set up - I'm not using DKIM or DMARC, just SPF for spam fighting.

Here's mine - I set mine up using this as a guide and while I follow it 90% of the way there are a few things I do differently - https://workaround.org/ispmail/jessie

Here's what is in my various files for hostnames.  Like you, I'm hosting multiple domains and they all work fine.

Reverse DNS is set to `mail.example.com`

I get a letsencrypt cert via the standalone method, and specify example.com, mail.example.com, and www.example.com as hosts on it.

`/etc/hostname` - `mailserver`  ( w/ appropriate mapping to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts`)
`/etc/mailname` - `mail.example.com`

In `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I have the following references to hostnames or FQDNs -

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
myhostname = mail.example.com
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.example.com, mailserver, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

In my `main.cf` I pull in the domains to service as well as users and passwords from a mysql database (per the howto I linked above).  Once I enter a domain in the proper table and create a user account or alias under it I can work as a mail server (incoming and outgoing) IF the other domain puts `mail.example.com` in as the highest priority (lowest number) MX record for the domain, and any SPF records they have specify that my `mail.example.com` is valid for sending - I use the MX record option

```
example.com. TXT  "v=spf1 a mx ptr ~all"
```

Clients connect to `mail.example.com` for Submission (w/ TLS/SSL) and pop3 and/or imap (both with tls/ssl).  Works great.